# Set destination is error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in a macro. It is an Excel, which after a filtering, copies the data in another Excel book. It is giving me the problem when I declare destiny, but I do not know what the problem is.

Could you help me?

```
Sub EnviarDatosVictoria()

    Dim wbLibroActual, wbLibroVictoria, wbLibroNuevo As Workbook
    Dim wsHojaActual, wsHojaVictoria As Worksheet
    Dim RangoDatos As Range
    Dim uFila As Long

    Dim RutaDestino As String

    RutaDestino = "Victoria.xlsx"

    'Datos Libro Actual
    Set wbLibroActual = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    Set wsHojaActual = wbLibroActual.ActiveSheet

    'Cogemos el rango que queremos copiar, que es todo lo usado
    Set RangoDatos = wsHojaActual.UsedRange

    'Establecemos el filtro
    RangoDatos.AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="OTRA"

    'Contamos el numero de filas (hasta la ultima)
    uFila = wsHojaActual.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copiar datos de filtro
    wsHojaActual.Range("A1:AM" & uFila).Copy

    'Datos Destino'
    Set wbLibroVictoria = Workbooks.Open(RutaDestino)
    Set wsHojaVictoria = wbLibroVictoria.Worksheets("Hoja1")

    wbHojaVictoria.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows(wbLibroActual.Name).Activate
    wsHojaActual.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

The error is this:

[image: Error 1004]

Comment: When opening a file it's safer to provide the full path, and not only the filename.

Comment: I'm not sure due to the spanish lines, but it seems you set your destination workbook based on `RutaDestino` variable. However, this variable has no full path...

Comment: Also -try pasting to the worksheet, not the workbook (and where do you want to paste exactly?)

Comment: I see lot of problems with this code. BTW this not how you set your autofilter range OR apply the filter OR copy the Filtered results OR open another workbook....

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim wsHojaActual, wsHojaVictoria As Worksheet` only the second is declared as type `Worksheet` but the first is of type `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim wsHojaActual As Worksheet, wsHojaVictoria As Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see lot of problems with this code. BTW this not how you set your autofilter range OR apply the filter OR copy the Filtered results OR open another workbook....

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you should not face any problems. This code is **UNTESTED** so if you spot an error, let me know and I will amend it. I am assuming that `Row 1` has headers.

```
Sub EnviarDatosVictoria()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim wbThatPath As String
    Dim rngToCopy As Range, rngAutofilter As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change path accordingly
    wbThatPath = "C:\Temp\Victoria.xlsx"

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Change the name of the sheet as applicable
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsThis
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngAutofilter = .Range("A1:AM" & lRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rngAutofilter
            '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and copy visible rows
            .AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="OTRA"

            '~~> Set your copy range
            Set rngToCopy = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Check if there is something in the copyrange or not
    '~~> If there is then open another workbook
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
        Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open(wbThatPath)
        Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("Hoja1")

        '~~> Copy Headers
        wsThis.Rows(1).Copy wsThat.Rows(1)
        '~~> Copy Filtered data
        rngToCopy.Copy wsThat.Rows(2)
    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a question, why not copy the headers in victoria.xlsx?

Comment: Oh you can. You can if you want to :)